# Hold-up time in SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I know the definition of Hold-up time in SMPS, and how to calculate the bulk capacitor. But I am wondering if someone can explain me how we define the hold-up time (sometimes 10ms, sometimes 16ms,...)? is it based on a  standard?
and why we need the hold-up time? what happen if we dont have it

Comment: What did your research in the question reveal? Tried a google search?

Answer (score 3):

There are standards that indirectly define hold-up times.

The standard ***IEC 61000-4-11*** Voltage dips, short interruptions and voltage variations immunity tests indirectly defines hold-up time when the product has to satisfy performance criteria A.
This [document](https://www.emcstandards.co.uk/files/61000-4-11_immunity_to_ac_supply_dips_dropouts__interruptions.pdf) shows some tests (e.g. voltage dip of 40% of 20 ms duration or voltage interruption of 60 ms duration).

For medical devices, the standard **IEC 60601-1** applies.
See this [document](https://www.us.tdk-lambda.com/media/292210/tdk-lambda-blog-052417.pdf) for some durations of voltage dips and interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

The hold up time specification is important to make sure that the power supply will keep working in case of an AC power outage.

If the system has no battery-based UPS, then the hold-up time needs to be longer then the maximum expected AC power outage duration. A typical requirement is 16 ms, which corresponds to an outage of the duration of one entire (60 Hz) AC cycle.

If the system has a battery-based UPS, then the hold-up time needs to be longer than the time it takes for the UPS to detect an AC failure, switch the power source to the battery and reestablish the proper AC voltage output that will feed the power supply.

The hold-up time is typically specified for a particular platform. Intel for instance specifies 17 ms for desktop power supplies. See [Resellers power supply design guide changes](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/design-guides/resellers-power-supply-design-guide-changes.pdf).

Comment: See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61020/voltage-hold-up-time-in-power-supply-design-for-desktop-form-factor