# Can a typical switching power supply hold up for 10ms?

Tags: relay, switch-mode-power-supply

Can a typical switching power supply for 3D printers hold up for 10ms? (average relay bounce time)

The printer draws 5amp@220 volt when heating the bed and the nozzles

The printer draws 5amp only when it is heating the bed, the normal operation is around 1 amp. I am trying to switch between 2 different UPS.

Comment: Welcome to SE EE. "Typical" power supplies do not exist. What do you mean by "hold up"? How is it relevant what current the printer draws?

Comment: Sounds very XY problem but any CE compliant power supply is required a certain hold-up time. I can’t the recall the exact number off the top of my head, but look up IEC 60950.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie He means - will it crash when the relay transfers power to another source. . || Printer energy (so V & I are relevant) is relevant to storage energy required. || You knew that :-)

Comment: @winny IEC 60950 is about product safety. You need to check the IEC 61000-4-11 Voltage dips, short interruptions and voltage variations immunity tests (ser also: [Hold up time in SMPS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/435540/hold-up-time-in-smps)

Comment: Why would you want to switch between two different UPS? The whole point of a UPS is to take care of this for you.

Comment: @Huisman Thanks! It’s been a while since I did consumer electronics. Is 61000-4-11 a requirement for passing 60950?

Comment: @winny For CE, is not any **standard** that forms a requirement. Only the **directives** have to be satisfied. I know that compliance with the IEC 61000-4-11 is one of the standards that quite well motivate the presumption you satisfied the EMC directive. And if i recall correctly, the IEC 60590 is quite good standard to motovate the presumption to satisfy the low voltage directive.

Comment: Y'All: Holdup time of psus is irrelevant here - it is holdup time of the relay contact that counts, or, in practice how long the load itself will holdup while a relay changeover toggles. My added extra relay contacts solution probably savs using the otherwise needed largsih caps.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: The OP is clearly asking about switching the AC power (coming from two different UPSs) to the input side of his 1 kW power supply. Answering this would require reverse-engineering the power supply in question, about which the OP has provided no information. Your answer provides some general guidelines on what to look for (but not expressed in those terms), while Tony's answer is more relevant to what was actually asked.

Comment: @DaveTweed You are correct, or essentially correct :-). Why, then, is the question "on hold"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holdup is dependant on stored energy.
It should not be necessary to hold-up the heaters over such a short period - only the electronics.

5A x 220 V x 10 ms =
E = V.I. t = 220 x 5 x 0.010 = 11 joules.
Sounds doable - lets see ...

In the following I calculate the capacitance required to **contain** the whole hold-up energy. However, in real-world applications you'll want the capacitor voltage to sag only a fraction of its full voltage so capacitor values need to be several times larger,
Sag 10% of V -  energy available = ~=20% of capacitor total energy
Sag 20% of V -  energy available = ~=36% of capacitor total energy
Sag 30% of V -  energy available = ~=50% of capacitor total energy

So if  you can tolerate a 30% voltage sag the capacitor values below need to be doubled. At least.

Stored capacitively,
E= 0.5 x C x V^2
C = 2.E/V^2

At 200V =  550 uF.
Large, doable.

At 12V = 0.15 F
= Supercap

At 12V 11J  ~+1 A.s = 0.25 mAh.
An extremely modest battery sufficeth.

E&OE, as ever
Efficiencies above are 100%. Allowance for real world "advisable"

---

**CHEATING:**

Connect a diode from each supply to the load.
Optionally add relat contacts C1 and C2 in series with thise diodes.
C0 is main changeover contact. 
C1 & C2 can be on same relay.

If C1 and C2 are not used then load will always operate from highest V supply if one is > 0.6v or so above the other OR the one selected by C0 if they are < 0.6V difference.

If C1 C2 used.

C1 C2 open - supply used is selected by C0.
Close C1 C2 - load will operate on "best supply"
Toggle C0 -load will prefer newly selected supply BUT will operate on either supply via diode if the other supply is low or no V.
Open C1 C2.

ALL contacts MAY be able to be on a suita ly timed relay with make before break contacts for C1 C2 and break before make for C0.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with good power supply designs, they always have enough storage energy for a 1 cycle dropout at rated load, so if using less than rated load, you may get more. The “one cycle” rule of thumb depends on your grid frequency and voltage and if it is a universal supply.

The other no-name supplies that do not fall in this “good design” category may be prone to glitches, brown-outs and surge loads that can easily degrade the dead time of AC input.  Since grid distribution often changes taps or switches power sources, this Rule of thumb is necessary for daily switching of grid power with < 1 cycle dropout.  Your region power stability may exceed these guidelines and you may experience more difficulty, which is why you should always get a power source much greater than your load requirements or rely on an always active UPS for a more reliable AC POWER.

If I understand your specs correctly  is 220Vac x 4A = 1KW ?? Then  a reliable UPS with more than adequate surge capability is better than switching between two. If that is input Vac and output DC then the former discussion about SMPS 1 cycle dropout applies.

Comment: It seems he is transferring BETWEEN supplies with a relay, so holdup of any given supply is irrelevant - he wants the LOAD to "hold itself up" while a relay transfers it between supplies.

Comment: Hmm...that could burn the contacts  @RussellMcMahon  if that's what was intended, there are some vague assumptions